# detach all body element and re-attach

Tags: html, printing

I have a js function the helps me to print

```
        var w = window.open();
        w.document.write('<!doctype html><html><head><style type="text/css">@page {margin: 0;} body { display: inline;}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/css/apex.min.css?v=4.2.6.00.03" type="text/css" /><!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/css/apex_ie.min.css?v=4.2.6.00.03" type="text/css"/><![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.22/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /></head><body>');

        w.document.write(var1);
        w.document.write(var2);

        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.document.close();
        w.focus();
        w.print();
        w.close();
```

The issue is it does everything in a new page, (window.open)

But I have to change it, so I have this idea

-hide everything (all body elements), so using DETACH
-re-attach my vars (vars1,vars2)
-print
-after is finished, re-attach all the body

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

BTW - I'm testing it on IE8

Comment: The best results for printing a web page are often achieved using CSS and the `@media print` rule that it supports. With this you can e.g. hide parts of your page that you don't want to be printed. Just search the web for `css media print tutorial`.

Comment: I've tried it, but on IE 8 doesn't work..
even I found that is supports media quieres